# I can't fetch data from Firebase to Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following a Youtube tutorial to learn more about storing data in Firebase and then interacting with it in Vue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Htt8AKeF1Kw (at 5:00 is the problem I'm facing)

Basically I follow everything there but the data doesn't show on my vue project and when I open console I see: ***onUnmounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup(). If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement.***

I'm loading 'animes' from Firebase with the following code on firebase.js

```
export const loadAnimes = () => {
const animes = ref([])
const close = animeCollection.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    animes.value = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id, ...doc.data()
    }))
    onUnmounted(close)  
    return animes
})
```

From this then I pass it to a component

**EDIT**: Fixed the issue, it was a mistake on my end, onMounted(close) and return animes should be 2 lines below

```
export const loadAnimes = () => {
const animes = ref([]) 
const close = animeCollection.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    animes.value = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id, ...doc.data()
    })) 
})
onUnmounted(close)
return animes
}
```

Comment: Would you kindly add all of the code involved in the display of this information? I noticed you added some information in a comment underneath the existing answer - though the lack of formatting makes it a little hard to read.

Comment: hi, sorry I forgot to edit my post, basically it was mistake on my end, onUnmounted(close) and return animes lines should have been two lines below after the }) brackets

Comment: Hey there, might I recommend posting it in an answer and accepting that answer? That way when people glance over this issue it'll be marked as "solved", otherwise they might just ignore it.

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot, still learning how to use Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was on my end, basically unMounted(close) and return anime should be two lines below

```
export const loadAnimes = () => {
const animes = ref([]) 
const close = animeCollection.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    animes.value = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id, ...doc.data()
    }))         
})
onUnmounted(close)  
return animes
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you wrote it in **setup()**?

````
setup() {
    onUnmounted(() => {
      ...
    })
}```
````

Comment: no I don't have it on setup, it's a separate js file, https://github.com/codingwithjustin/vue-firebase-crud/blob/main/src/firebase.js here's the github from same tutorial, he then passes it at /components/UserList.vue

Comment: Please look file UserList.vue line:35 :)

Comment: thank you but I already have that as: setup() {
    const animes = loadAnimes();
    return { animes };
  }, the main problem must be in the method

Comment: I don't think so, your above method looks correct, please share your listing page code

Comment: <template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="{ id, name, likes } in animes" :key="id">
      {{ name }} -{{ likes }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { loadAnimes } from "../views/firebase";
export default {
  setup() {
    const animes = loadAnimes()
    return { animes}
  }
}
</script>